# Orbital obliquity of the Earth

Tags: orbital-motion, astronomy, earth, celestial-mechanics, solar-system

Consider that we have all the orbital parameters that characterize the Earth. How would one calculate the orbital obliquity of Earth?

One could argue that since the rotation of Earth doesn't change its obliquity, it would be the same as the inclination, which has the following expression: $$\cos(i) = \frac{h_z}{h},$$ where $h_z$ is the z-component of the orbital momentum, and $h$ is the norm of the orbital momentum.

However, this assumption doesn't hold for other systems. My questions are:

1. How would one calculate the obliquity knowing the orbital parameters of Earth?
2. Why, in some cases, is the inclination the same as the obliquity?

Comment: We generally measure the orbital planes of the planets (and asteroids) relative to the ecliptic, i.e., Earth's orbital plane. However, it's sometimes preferable to use the invariable plane of the Solar System https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/a/44412/16685